# Wordpress causes high CPU usage (mysqld)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysqld, cpu

I have a **wordpress** site with 500k posts in MYSQL database running on debian dedicated server:

**Server OS**: Debian 8 "Jesssie)" - Linux version 4.9.58-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 (kernel@kernel.ovh.net) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Mon Oct 23 11:35:59 CEST 2017 (Ispconfig)

**Web server**: Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

**PHP**: PHP Version 7.1.8

**Procesor**: Intel 2x Xeon E5-2630v3 - 16/32t - 2.4GHz /3.2GHz

**RAM**: 128GB DDR4 ECC 1866 MHz

**Disks**: SoftRaid 2x450GB SSD NVMe

Today I noticed that MySQL is causing a high CPU usage:

> 2383 mysql     20   0 68.666g 7.596g  11152 S  **2435%**  6.0 108:43.00
>   mysqld

**top**:

```
top - 18:05:42 up 6 min,  1 user,  load average: 23.29, 14.22, 6.09
Tasks: 548 total,   4 running, 544 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 25.8 us, 61.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 13.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 25.2 us, 57.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 17.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 24.7 us, 49.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 26.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 53.6 us, 15.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 30.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  : 27.0 us, 43.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 30.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  : 24.8 us, 41.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 33.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  : 59.3 us, 31.8 sy,  0.0 ni,  8.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 21.6 us, 63.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 15.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  : 41.5 us, 40.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 18.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  : 51.5 us, 35.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 12.5 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 : 41.0 us, 39.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 19.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 : 55.4 us, 33.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 11.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 : 76.9 us, 10.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 13.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu13 : 81.7 us,  3.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 15.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu14 : 31.8 us, 43.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 25.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu15 : 35.3 us, 58.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  6.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu16 : 24.4 us, 52.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 23.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu17 : 26.0 us, 64.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  9.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu18 : 34.9 us, 36.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 28.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu19 : 20.0 us, 46.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 33.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu20 : 86.3 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 12.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu21 : 36.2 us, 51.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 12.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu22 : 25.5 us, 46.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 28.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu23 : 19.7 us, 41.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 38.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu24 : 62.3 us,  4.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 33.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu25 : 26.3 us, 60.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 12.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu26 : 57.3 us, 24.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 18.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu27 : 73.6 us,  7.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 18.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu28 : 21.7 us, 42.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 35.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu29 : 43.3 us, 37.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 19.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu30 : 26.2 us, 57.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 15.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu31 : 28.2 us, 65.8 sy,  0.0 ni,  5.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  13198007+total, 16391500 used, 11558857+free,    86084 buffers
KiB Swap:  1046520 total,        0 used,  1046520 free.  5456440 cached Mem
```

**show full processlist;**

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id   | User          | Host      | db            | Command | Time | State                | Info                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1541 | root          | localhost | NULL          | Query   |    0 | NULL                 | show full processlist                                                                                                                                                                |
| 1604 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Sending data         | SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = '2018/01/amp.jpg'                                                                              |
| 1605 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Sending data         | SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = '2018/01/amp.jpg'                                                                              |
| 1610 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    0 | Sorting result       | SELECT  t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tt.count > 0 ORDER BY tt.count DESC LIMIT 45 |
| 1611 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    6 | Sorting result       | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1613 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    5 | Sorting result       | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1614 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    4 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1615 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    3 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1616 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    3 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1617 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1618 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1619 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1620 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1621 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1622 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    2 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1623 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1624 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1625 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1626 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Sending data         | SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = '2018/01/amp.jpg'                                                                              |
| 1627 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Sending data         | SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = '2018/01/amp.jpg'                                                                              |
| 1628 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1629 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    1 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1630 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    0 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 1631 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    0 | Sending data         | SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = '2018/01/amp.jpg'                                                                              |
| 1632 | c1database | localhost | c1database | Query   |    0 | Sending data         | SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = '2018/01/amp.jpg'                                                                              |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**my.cnf (MySQL):**

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 61440M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=60
key_buffer              = 2048M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type        = 0
#query_cache_size        = 8192M
```

**25 queries** have caused my MySQL to generate over **2435% CPU usage**. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) current SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High CPU and/or slow queries -- must fix the queries and/or indexes and/or design.

The schema for wp_postmeta is poorly designed.  See the tips in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for how to improve it.

Are your tables ENGINE=MyISAM?  Or ENGINE=InnoDB?  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory) for the one change to make to `my.cnf` to take better advantage of your 128GB of RAM, which is probably very underutilized.

Even after the above changes, you may still have some nasty queries.  [*Find them*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) so we (in another Question) can discuss how to speed them up.